# Laravel Carbon - get interval slots with buffer duration

Tags: php, laravel, date, timestamp, php-carbon

I need to get time slots interval with buffer time between slots and without invalid time intervals.

I have this variables:

```
$serviceDuration = 40; // 40 minutes slots duration
$serviceBufferDuration = 5; // 5 minutes buffer time between slots
$invalidTimeIntervals = ['10:40 - 11:00', '12:10 - 12:30']; // invalid time intervals
$startWorking = "09:00";
$endWorking =  "13:30";
```

And I want a response like this:

```
[
   "09:00 - 09:40",
   "09:45 - 10:25",
   "11:00 - 11:40", // this starts at 11:00 because has invalid time interval from 10:40 to 11:00
   "11:45 - 11:55",
   "12:30 - 13:10" // this starts at 12:30 because has invalid time interval from 12:10 to 12:30
];
```

[Time slots example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHPdj.png)

Thank you!

Comment: why 10 minutes gap `11:45 - 11:55` in your response? If it is mistake then I will answered it.

Comment: @JSTECH, yes is a mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just trying to get your response but it may be short.

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$start_time = Carbon::parse($startWorking);
$end_time = Carbon::parse($endWorking);

$times = [];

$loop = true;
while($loop) {

    foreach ($invalidTimeIntervals as $interval) {
        $invalidTime = explode(' - ', $interval);
        $invalidTime[0] = Carbon::parse($invalidTime[0]);
        $invalidTime[1] = Carbon::parse($invalidTime[1]);

        $slot_time = $start_time->copy()->addMinutes($serviceDuration);

        if ($start_time->lessThan($invalidTime[0])
            && ( $slot_time->greaterThan($invalidTime[1])
                || $slot_time->between($invalidTime[0], $invalidTime[1])
            )
        ) {
            $start_time = Carbon::parse($invalidTime[1]);
        }
    }

    $slot_time = $start_time->copy()->addMinutes($serviceDuration);

    if ($slot_time->lessThanOrEqualTo($end_time)) {
        $times[] =  $start_time->format('H:i').' - '. $slot_time->format('H:i');
        $start_time = $slot_time->addMinutes($serviceBufferDuration);
        continue;
    }

    $loop = false;
}

return $times;
```

Output

```
[
    "09:00 - 09:40",
    "09:45 - 10:25",
    "11:00 - 11:40",
    "12:30 - 13:10"
]
```